# Limit With order by takes long time in mysql for only 10 records

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

Here is my query which takes more than 5 second s to fetch 10 records n time gets bigger by changing the offsets in limit clause.
Table contain 12 million records.

```
SELECT device_id
    ,media_id
    ,limit1.play_date
    ,limit1.start_time
    ,limit1.end_time
    ,SUBTIME(limit1.end_time, limit1.start_time) AS playback_duration
FROM device_media_log
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT play_date
        ,start_time
        ,end_time
        ,device_media_id
    FROM device_media_log
    ORDER BY play_date DESC
        ,start_time DESC
        ,end_time DESC limit 0
        ,10
    ) AS limit1 ON device_media_log.device_media_id = limit1.device_media_id;
```

explain plan::

```
+----+-------------+------------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------------------------+---------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table            | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                    | rows    | Extra          |
+----+-------------+------------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------------------------+---------+----------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>       | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                   |      10 |                |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | device_media_log | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | limit1.device_media_id |       1 |                |
|  2 | DERIVED     | device_media_log | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                   | 8345645 | Using filesort |
+----+-------------+------------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------------------------+---------+----------------+
```

here is create table::

```
CREATE TABLE `device_media_log` (
  `device_media_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `device_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `media_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `playback_type_id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `playback_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `play_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`device_media_id`),
  KEY `Index_media_id` (`media_id`),
  KEY `Index_device_id` (`device_id`),
  KEY `Index_play_date` (`play_date`),
  KEY `Index_start_time` (`start_time`),
  KEY `Index_end_time` (`end_time`),
  KEY `Index_client_id` (`client_id`)
) 
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8366229 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Describe after adding compound index
-+-------+---------------+----------------- +---------+------+------+-------+ 
| 1 | SIMPLE | device_media_log | index | NULL | index_composite | 12 | NULL | 10 | |

Comment: please format your code next time (i've done this for you now). nobody is willing to help you if you don't even try to present readable code.

Comment: show create table device_media_log

Comment: if you don't have one, try an index on play_date (or play_date, start_time, end_time)

Comment: indexes are already exists.

Comment: Thanks Oezi for ur kind support.

Comment: How to format the code here?

Comment: Put this (with some data) into sqlfiddle, just an advice to increase your chances of getting it answered.

Comment: Why are you doing a sub query at all? Why not have the `ORDER` and `LIMIT` clause on the main query?

Comment: main query took more time than this one , i just modify the original simple query into this to avoid more large offsets.

Comment: Why does it take longer? What's the `describe` for that?

Comment: i dnt knw the reason. I am new ti this one.

Comment: What's the `DESCRIBE` like when you don't use sub query?

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
SELECT device_id
   ,media_id
   ,limit1.play_date
   ,limit1.start_time
   ,limit1.end_time
   ,SUBTIME(limit1.end_time, limit1.start_time) AS playback_duration
FROM 
   device_media_log
ORDER BY 
    play_date DESC
    ,start_time DESC
    ,end_time DESC 
limit 0, 10;
```

There is no need of subquery as you are directly using the result.
Also the explain statement shows that none of your created index is used.

Create a compound index on following column `play_date, start_time, end_time`.

```
ALTER TABLE device_media_log ADD INDEX device_media_log_date_time(play_date, start_time, end_time);
```

hope this helps...

Comment: My original query is the same but it took more time than i wrote now using subquery n limit is not only 10, limit use with offset by any number, example N,M, like 0,10  500000,10    6547383,10 and etc

Comment: Don't change the query, just add necessary indexes and it will solve your problem as I have mentioned in the answer..

Comment: I add copmound index and than try simple query ,it takes more than 19 sec.